# Can i create a custom control which is using another custom control in Generic.xml

Tags: wpf

I want to create a custom control which should display a stylish ComboBox inside it. 
So 1. LeafControl and 2. LeafComboBox.

I have Kept both the ControlTemplate styles in the same Generic.xaml file, which is not correct i guess. Because during initialization of LeafControl depends upon the template creation of LeafComboBox.

So during loading i am getting exception :

Error Msg:

> "The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'ControlsLibrary.LeafComboBox' that matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception."}"

Inner Error Msg :

> "{"PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'LeafControl'."}

Hence, where should i define the Generics.xml Templates so that i can use customcontrol2 in customcontrol1.

Best Regards,
Manoranjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly legal to provide the default `Style`s for *all* of your `CustomControl`s in the one `generic.xaml` file. Your problem is that you have (probably) copied and pasted one (or more) of your `DependencyProperty`s from your `LeafControl` control to your other control, but not updated the `OwnerType` property.

Just search for `LeafControl` in your `LeafComboBox` control and replace it with `LeafComboBox` instead. You can't define the same property for the same object twice, you see.

Comment: I found the problem, you were mostly write, i had another dependcy property with the same name. that is why i was getting error message - "{"PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'LeafControl'."}